# TestNG parallel execution reports test cases as Skipped

Tags: java, testng

I have around 1000 test cases in my TestNG project. I tried to run them parallely with 100 threads and parallel="classes". But only 40 test cases ran and rest were reported as skipped.
But when I tried with 15 threads, it is working fine.

I am doubting resource unavailability but should not it wait until resource are available.

Do I need to write any specific code for it to spawn 100 threads and execute all 1000 test cases.

PS - All tests are independent of each other

Comment: Do you see any log message before the tests are skipped?

Comment: No, they are simply reported as skipped

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Did you set the verbosity level of the output to verbose or debug?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE and I have n't set the verbosity level. I will try and revert

Comment: `Skipped` in TestNG means that the preconditions to run the test were not met. It's difficult to say what might be the issue without the code. You must have dependencies between your tests and an error in a dependency is making testNG skip the tests.

Comment: @Augusto All the test cases are independent of each other. Also they are executing successfully if I set the thread cont to 15